# How to convert this Makefile into CMakeList.txt?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am not familiar with both Makefile and CMake, I want to convert this 3rd-party Makefile to CMakeList.txt so that this 3rd-party code can compile with latest DLib code, but I have no idea how.

I just know some basic CMake command, but this file has a lot of flags and command options, I'm feel very clueless now.

```
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS = -g -I./include -I./src/dlib/all/source.cpp -ljpeg -mavx -lm -lpthread -lX11 -DDLIB_HAVE_BLAS -DNDEBUG  -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT -DDLIB_HAVE_AVX  -O3 `pkg-config --cflags opencv `

LDFLAGS = -ljpeg -mavx -lm -lpthread -lX11 `pkg-config --libs opencv` -DDLIB_HAVE_BLAS -DNDEBUG  -DDLIB_JPEG_SUPPORT -DDLIB_HAVE_AVX  -O3

all: bin/oic

bin/oic: obj/dlib.o obj/faceDetection.o obj/pupilDetection.o obj/kalmanFilters.o obj/util.o obj/oic.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# Should use findpackage(DLib) instead
#obj/dlib.o: ./src/dlib/all/source.cpp
#obj/dlib.o: ../../Dlib/dlib-19.7/dlib/all/source.cpp
#   mkdir -p obj bin
#   $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

obj/faceDetection.o: ./src/faceDetection.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

obj/pupilDetection.o: ./src/pupilDetection.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

obj/kalmanFilters.o: ./src/kalmanFilters.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

obj/util.o: ./src/util.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<

obj/oic.o: ./src/oic.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $<


.PHONY: all oic

clean:
    rm -rf obj/*.o
    rm -rf bin/oic
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating CMakeLists file from existing Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985839/creating-cmakelists-file-from-existing-makefile)

Comment: `this file has a lot of flags and command options, I'm feel very clueless now.` - We are not code writer service. Take one command in Makefile, try to convert it to CMake, in case of difficultes use search. If search doesn't help, ask here about specific command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, OP is looking for an `entry point`. Why not give him/her a couple of hints? He/she would still have to figure out complete solution him- or herself. OP might be in a situation when he/she does not have time to learn CMake from A to Z.

Comment: Of course I didn't mean SO is a code writer service, sorry for unintentionally making you feel like that. In fact, @Angew 's answer is really a SO-appropriate style of answering questions. At least I didn't ask: "How to do bubble sort in C++" and then woola someone provides a fully running code (You can make a search in SO for these kinds of situations). I said clearly that "I am clueless", and giving some clues is enough for me to mark a response as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few pointers that should get you on the right track:

- `-g` is normally correctly set up by CMake itself and doesn't need to be touched.
- `-O3` is candidate for replacement by [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) or by adding it to appropriate [`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_*`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_RELEASE.html).
- `-D` flags are candidates for replacement by [`target_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) or by playing around with [`add_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html).
- `-I` is candidate for replacement by [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) or [`include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html).
- `-l` is candidtate for replacement by [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).
- The invocation of `pkg-config` will likely need replacing by a suitable [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html).
- The rule for `bin/oic` will have to be replaced by [`add_executable()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html).

Comment: Thank you, these are really helpful pointers that I can base on to walk myself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your code so I can only show the possible equivalents to the lines you have:

You are creating executable. In CMake this is done with [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_executable.html).

```
add_executable(oic source-file1.cpp source-file2.cpp ...)
```

This commands ensures that `oic` **executable target** is created.
When you build this target you will have `oic` binary at the end.

Equivalent lines for setting the flags:

```
set_target_properties(oic PROPERTIES LDFLAGS "your link flags")
set_target_properties(oic PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "your compile flags")
```

Google for `Properties on Targets` and `set_target_properties`.

So the skeleton for your `CMakeLists.txt` file should be:

---

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
# cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1) # you don't need this at this point

project(oic)
enable_language(C CXX)

set(oic_sources
  src/faceDetection.cpp
  src/pupilDetection.cpp
  src/kalmanFilters.cpp
  src/util.cpp
  src/oic.cpp
)

add_executable(oic ${oic_sources})

set_target_properties(oic PROPERTIES LDFLAGS "your link flags")
set_target_properties(oic PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "your compile flags")
```

---

**Build the project**

Let's assume that you have folder `oic_root` in which you have `oic` project in which there are your `src/*.cpp` files. Assume you are in that folder:

```
$ oic> cd ..
$ oic_root> make oic_build
$ oic_root> cd oic_build
$ oic_build> cmake ../oic -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

Comment: It should get you somewhere, please ask further questions if you follow this somehow.

Comment: Thank you, I learnt a lot from your and Angew's answers, now I feel I have clues to walk on myself.